# How can I test if the django rest form output contains some value?

Tags: django-rest-framework

The django rest framework forms related fields sometimes leak things I don't want. I want to write a test for it.

I tried this:

```
class CVRequestAPITests(APITestCase):
    def test_disallow_read_access(self):
        url = reverse('cvrequest-list')
        response = self.client.get(url, headers={
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml'
        })
```

But it still gives JSON.

Comment: Why do you want HTML here? You can perfectly test with JSON. It's even better, because it reflects actual usage.

Comment: @KarinaKlinkevičiūtė It doesn't. The HTML form outputs options the JSON doesn't because the HTML form is a helper view, it's not part of the API.